# If a user is already logged on. then he should be moved to home page but not working

Tags: php

I am facing a problem while testing simple basic php site that is if user is already logged on then header should move to home.php whenever he tries to visit login page. how to set up this?The code used is:
**For login.php:**

```
<body>
<center>
<font color=red>
<?php

if(isset($_GET['msg']))
echo $_GET['msg'];
?>
</font>
<form action=logcheck.php method=post>
User ID:<input type=text  name=uid><br>
Password:<input type=password  name=pass><br>
<input type=submit value=Login>
</form>
</body>
```

**For logincheck:**

```
<?php
$u=$_POST['uid'];
$p=$_POST['pass'];

if($u==='rkgec' && $p==='123')
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['usrid']=$u;
    $_SESSION['passwd']=$p;
    header("Location: home.php");

}
else
    header("Location:login.php?msg=User ID or PAssword Not Match...!");
?>
```

**For home.php**

```
<body bgcolor=pink>
<h1>Welcome, RKGEC</h1>
<br>
<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['usrid']===null || $_SESSION['passwd']===null)
    header('location:login.php');

echo "<font color=green><b>USER ID :$_SESSION[usrid]<br>";

echo "Password :$_SESSION[passwd]<br>";

?>
<a href=logout.php>LOGOUT</a>
</body>
```

Comment: You need to show the code that you've tried...

Comment: @NijrajGelani it is clearly evident from the question that he isn't sure how to go about doing this and hasn't attempted.

Comment: The code i have tried is added above. I tried already thus the problem encountered.

Answer (score 1):

While logging in, add a new element to the user's session and set its value to true.

Like so.

```
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
```

And in your login page you can do a check like so.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] === true)
{
   header("Location: home.php");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But still problem exists. I am running code on xampp for windows.

Answer (score 1):

Haider Ali's answer is probably better but here's a simpler way

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION['logged_in'] == true) {
  header("Location: home.php");
} else {
  header("Location: login.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But still problem exists.